# Getting Page Load Progress with Ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Well, i am new to Ajax and JQuery, I struggled to compile this. I'm trying to load URL with ajax navigation and with popstate retrieving back and front navigations. The below code works well but my problem is integrating the Progress Indicator of the page i'm trying to load when the link is clicked using [Pace Page Progress Bar Plugin](http://github.hubspot.com/pace/docs/welcome/).

```
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<div id="render-me">
<title>jQuery Ajax Test</title>
<script type="text/javascript" src=" https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://www.gossipper.com/content/css/inspired-mob/styles/pace-theme-center-atom.css" />

  <script>
    paceOptions = {
  ajax: true, // disabled
  document: true, // disabled
  eventLag: true, // disabled
  elements: {
    selectors: ['#render-me']
  }
};
  </script>
  <script src="https://www.gossipper.com/content/css/inspired-mob/js/pace.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript"><!--

$(document).ready(function(e){
    $.ajaxSetup ({
        cache: false
    });
    var page;
    $('a.lnk').click(function(){

        page = $(this).attr('href');

        $('#render-me').load(page + ' #render-me');

        if(page != location.href){
          window.history.pushState({path:page},'',page);
          $(window).bind("popstate", function() {
              link = location.pathname.replace(/^.*[\\/]/, ""); // get filename only
    $('#render-me').load(link + ' #render-me');
});
        }       

        return false;
    });
    document.addEventListener('gg', function(){
      document.querySelector('.pace').classList.remove('pace-inactive');
      document.querySelector('.pace').classList.add('pace-active');

      document.querySelector('.pace-progress').setAttribute('data-progress-text', percentComplete.value + '%');
      document.querySelector('.pace-progress').setAttribute('style', '-webkit-transform: translate3d(' + percentComplete.value + '%, 0px, 0px)');
    });
    $(window).on({
        popstate:function(e){
            page = location.href;
            $('#render-me').load(page + ' #render-me');
        }
    });

});
</script>
</head>
<body>
<h1>Web page test.html</h1>
<a href="https://www.gossipper.com/forum/general/news/22853-dino-melaye-injured-rushed-to-hospital-after-jumping-off-a-police-vehicle" title="Get extern" class="lnk">Get extern</a>

<div id="content">Initial content in test.html</div>

</body>
</div>
</html>
```

As i stated above, am a newbie to Ajax, JQuery and Javascript. I struggled to compile this, i need help getting this to work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem in your code is your script source for pace, css source for pace and the proper placing of html elements.

I tried to go in the sources of your script and css for pace but it is not found.
You don't need to encapsulate all of your element in the `<div id="render-me">`.

Based from https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_head.asp

The `<head>` element is a container for metadata (data about data) and is placed between the `<html>` tag and the `<body>` tag.
HTML metadata is data about the HTML document. Metadata is not displayed.
Metadata typically define the document title, character set, styles, links, scripts, and other meta information.
The following tags describe metadata: `<title>`, `<style>`, `<meta>`, `<link>`, `<script>`, and `<base>`

So you must remove the div in the head, fix the sources and put the `<div id="render-me">` inside body.

Here is your code that I fixed: https://jsfiddle.net/uqbysq1a/1/

Comment: Amazing! I want the loading atom to cover the whole page (placing it at the center) when the link is clicked (all the content on the page will disappear). How do i go about that? (Please help re-edit the code).

Comment: And also In the `<head>` part of the page am trying to load, i have a link to a css that only applied to the page i'm trying to load. That's why i start the rendering element render-me from the `<head>`. How do i load the whole page so that `<head>` of the page I'm trying to grab will be grabbed too.